# java - a specific unicode character cannot be displayed

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

Below is my code to display the unicode character but then there's only one unicode character can't be displayed. Why?

```
byte extra[] = " ‘ ’ ” “ 《 》 ： ； ” ".getBytes();
String extravalue = new String(extra, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(extravalue);
```

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuYdh.png)

 As you can see from the picture above, the character ' ” ' is displayed as ' ?? ' and others are displayed as their original character. Why? 

 What can I do in order to display it? 
I want to do a comparison with the character above with a string inside a file.

Comment: google java escape char

Comment: @Stultuske i did try that but is an illegal escape character

Comment: Hmmm... works good for me. Make sure the **font** you're using for your console window can handle the character. Use Monospaced.

Comment: @DevilsHnd thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You *also* need to specify the encoding when you call `String.getBytes()`, otherwise it takes the default encoding of your platform. And in your case, it's possible that this isn't `UTF-8`:

```
byte extra[] = " ‘ ’ ” “ 《 》 ： ； ” ".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

You need to do this in any case, if you want to run your code correctly on different platforms / operating systems.

However, your case is strange. I've tried with the normal character sets for different platforms, including CP1252 and CP1250, and that gives question marks for all characters.

It's also possible that your font doesn't support a particular character. However, it seems very unlikely that your font supports the "left double quotation mark" but not the "right double quotation mark".

Comment: if i do that, all the other character are gone as well. :'(
Anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: The left quotation mark in unicode is 0x201C and right one is 0x201D, and i print out extravalue.contains("\u0x201D") and the result is false while if i print out extravalue.contains("\u0x201C") the result is true, and yea it's weird that my font doesn't support the right double quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

Put those character inside a file and read it using a scanner and somehow it works. Wow...  ._.